# Bounties offered.by me

Tags: discussion, support

Can bounties offered  by me can turn out to be disadvantageous for me?

Answer (score 1):

[Help clearly states that offering a bounty always costs you](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

> All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.

> If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any privileges, you will lose access to those privileges.

> You may not cancel a bounty once it has been started.

The utility of bounties on martial arts for question visibility is very low. The volume of questions on martial arts is low enough that most everyone will see any question you post.

Comment: ^_^ And, because volume is low, it can make one a bit less inclined to give a big bounty just as a reward. On an active site, I can make a 200+ bounty back up in a day or two. Here... I maybe get an upvote every day or two on average.